# Formatting a multidimensional array Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I want to turn the list comprehension below to a 3 dimensional array where it prints out the `last index, max , min` of each of the iterations in the array. The `(arr[i:] > 0).cumsum()/ np.arange(1, len(arr[i:])+1) * 100)` function below calculates the the `number of positive array values/ length of array` so in the first array `[12,12,-3,-1,2,1]` 4 out of the 6 values are positive and so it is `66.66`% as the ending result. However if you only intake the first 2 indexes `[12,12.....]` it is `100` % so that was the max efficient value and if you take in the first 4 indexes `[12,12,-3,-1]` the efficiency will drop to `50`%. The `last_inc, maxs , mins` does not work below but the `result` does. How would I be able to incorporate the `last_inc, maxs , mins` in the code and get the Expected Output below?

```
import numpy as np 

def run(*args):
    
    result = np.array([np.array([((arr[i:] > 0).cumsum()/ np.arange(1, len(arr[i:])+1) * 100) for i in range(len(arr))],dtype=object) for arr in args], dtype=object)
    last_inc = result[-1]
    maxs = np.max(result)
    mins = np.min(result)
            
run(np.array([12,12,-3,-1,2,1]), np.array([-3,-1,-2,1]), np.array([12,-12]))
```

Expected Output:

```
last_indexes[[66.66666666666666, 60.0, 50.0, 66.66666666666666, 100.0, 100.0], [25.0, 33.33333333333333, 50.0, 100.0], [50.0, 0.0]]
max[[100.0, 100.0, 50.0, 66.66666666666666, 100.0, 100.0],[25.0, 33.33333333333333, 50.0, 100.0],[100.0, 0.0]]
min[[50.0, 33.33333333333333, 0.0, 0.0, 100.0, 100.0]]
```

Comment: `formatting` usually deals in string displays of an object such as an array.  That doesn't appear to be the case here.  While you show expected output, you don't show what `run` produces, whether it's an error or unexpected output.  Don't expect every reader to copy-n-paste the code and run it themselves.

Comment: Speaking of formatting, that code line that requires horizontal scrolling to read, much less comprehend, is a big turn off.  Why spend time on a question where so little thought has been given to making it reader friendlly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

numpy looks like a terrible tool for what you're doing. your list comprehension is what prevents you from getting the job done. you'll have to do some filtering on the mins, and maybe wrap the code

```
def run2(arr):
    last_incs=np.zeros_like(arr, float)
    maxs=np.zeros_like(arr, float)
    mins=np.zeros_like(arr, float)
    for i in range(arr.size):
        result=np.cumsum(arr[i:]>0)/np.arange(1,arr[i:].size+1)*100
        last_incs[i]=result[-1]
        maxs[i]=np.max(result)
        mins[i]=np.min(result)
    print(last_incs,maxs,mins)
            
for arr in [
        np.array([12,12,-3,-1,2,1]), 
        np.array([-3,-1,-2,1]), 
        np.array([12,-12])]:
    run2(arr)
```